# is there anything in javascript that can convert "August" to 8?

Tags: javascript, date

i need to convert Monthname to integer of that month (and want to avoid a big switch statement).  any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just create a date in that month, parse it, and use `getMonth()` like this

```
function convertMonthNameToNumber(monthName) {
    var myDate = new Date(monthName + " 1, 2000");
    var monthDigit = myDate.getMonth();
    return isNaN(monthDigit) ? 0 : (monthDigit + 1);
}

alert(convertMonthNameToNumber("August"));     //returns 8
alert(convertMonthNameToNumber("Augustsss"));  //returns 0 (or whatever you change the default too)
alert(convertMonthNameToNumber("Aug"));        //returns 8 - Bonus!
alert(convertMonthNameToNumber("AuGust"));     //returns 8 - Casing is irrelevant!
```

Comment: I like this. For completeness, what will happen if I pass an invalid month (like "Äugust")?

Comment: Worth mentioning that that *Date.parse()* returns a number representing the date, not an actual date object.  Also *getMonth()* will return *7*, not *8* because months are zero-based.

Comment: You beat me to it! But actually, this is wrong anyways :). `Date.parse` returns a number, which doesn't have the getMonth property. Try `var myDate = new Date(Date.parse(monthName + " 1, 2000"))`

Comment: @Pekka, rewritten, to return 0 if the month is invalid

Comment: @Andy E, nice catches.  I initially wrote it from memory, hadn't written tests yet.  Should be good to go now though.

Comment: Personally, I would have have just returned `NaN` instead of 0. Seems to make more sense to me. Since it converts a month to name to a name, returning `NaN` would make it clear that it was not able to convert it. Thought that's just me being picky, and not by any means correct.

Comment: @Daniel, depends on how you are using it I suppose, but yes, `0` was a bad choice on my part, should probably be `NaN` or `null`, it was more just a placeholder to show that you need to check for `NaN` and can return whatever you want in that case.

Answer (score 4):

```
var monthtbl = { 'January': 1, 'February': 2, /* ... */, 'August', 8, /* ... */, 'December': 12 };
// ...
var monthNumber = monthtbl[monthName];
```

*edit* but do it the way @Chad suggests :-)

If you wanted to make it insensitive to alphabetic case, you'd create the object ("monthtbl") all lower-case and then use

```
var monthNumber = monthtbl[monthName.toLowerCase()];
```

Comment: This is solid. Out of interest: how would I make this case insensitive? In case I need to parse a user input?

Comment: FWIW, this will obviously be faster if you're doing this many times.

Comment: generate the array in uppercase, and uppercase the user input before checking the array.

Comment: @Pointy, as mentioned, this has the downside of casing, and what if the month name were just **Aug** ?

Answer (score 3):

You can create an array(name/vale pairs) in your code since it's only 12 months and write a function to do it.

```
var months = {August: 8};
```

Comment: that not much different than a big switch statement but definately a backup idea

Comment: Not a big switch statement, Pointy has the same idea.  it's only two lines of code for you.

Answer (score 2):

Another option just to throw out there, you could use an array and [`$.inArry()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/), like this:

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
function getMonth(name) {
  return $.inArray(name, months) +1;
}
```

Though judging by your previous questions, pulling the date directly from the jquery UI datepicker object may be much easier.

Comment: Yikes!  No need for jQuery here.

Comment: It could be replaced with Array.indexOf, but that isn't cross browser friendly.

Comment: @palswim it seems that "ooo" is already using jQuery because many of his recent questions are thusly tagged.

Comment: @palswim - I agree in general, but I've answered some of the OPs previous questions so have a bit more information about his setup :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function monthToNumber(month) {
    return new Date(Date.parse("1 "+month)).getMonth()+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here value holds the month name value

```
var month1 = value;
month1 = month1.toLowerCase();
var months = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",   "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
month1 = months.indexOf(month1);
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in brief to make it more useful for OP and other readers.